# Show time and date in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I'm using Gnome classic in Ubuntu 12.04. I inadvertently deleted some files, and after that  I'm not able to find the settings that would allow me to display the date and time.
 How  can I make the date and time appear?

Comment: Please give us more details about your problem. Where should date and time be shown? Which files do you have deleted? ...

Answer (score 1):

You may have deleted the `indicator-datetime` package. Make sure it's installed, then logout/login.